# How can I access my WSL2 docker volume data from other locations, such as a Ubuntu 20.04 distribution?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’ve installed Docker Desktop for Windows and a Ubuntu 20.04 distribution on my Windows 10 machine.  I’ve been able to setup some containers and volumes.  On my Win 10 machine, I can access this volume by using this in Windows Explorer

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes
```

When I’m connected to my WSL2 Ubuntu distribution, I see under `/mnt` entries for all of my hard drives and one called wsl.  However, when I browse to

```
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data
```

There is no “community” folder.  How can I access this directory?

Indeed, how can I access this wsl share from a different machine than is running the wsl2 kernel?

Comment: What's your end goal in accessing those volumes from outside a container?  There are probably a few options depending on your needs.  Also, just a heads-up that `\\wsl$` under Windows is *not* the same as `/mnt/wsl` from inside WSL.  `/mnt/wsl` is an ephemeral (tmpfs) directory set up to allow sharing between WSL instances.  By "default", `/mnt/wsl` is empty when starting up WSL -- What you see in there is being created by Docker Desktop.  Apparently Docker Desktop doesn't have a need to expose the volume data to other instances that way.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found a solution somewhere on SO but I can't remember where, so here it is:
in windows cmd execute similar to:

```
net use h: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data
```

in WSL2 Ubuntu execute:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/wsl2
sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/wsl2
```

Now you should be able to access docker volumes using this mount.